# Some of my google analytic events are not reflecting after 24 hours

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

Here is my code :

HTML part :

```
<div class="subscribe">
  <a href="#' title="library_membership">Subscribe for a Month</a>
  <a href="#' title="library_membership">Subscribe for a Year</a>
</div>
```

Javascript :

```
$js('div.subscribe a').live('click', function(e) {
    var This =  $(this);
    e.preventDefault();
    if(This.html().indexOf("Month") != -1)
        _gaq.push(["_trackEvent", "Subscriptions", "Clicked Month", This.attr( "title" )]);
    else 
        _gaq.push(["_trackEvent", "Subscriptions", "Clicked Year", This.attr( "title" )]);

});
```

I tried ga_debug.js to confirm if my events are pushed to google analytics and they are indeed showing up on the chrome console.

However, even after 24 hours, my clicks on "Subscribe for a Year" are not showing up on google analytics. My clicks on "Subscribe for a Month" have showed up. Can anyone help me why I am not getting the accurate data on google analytics.

Answer (score 2):

Clean up your javascript/jquery and it should work:

```
$('div.subscribe a').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).html().indexOf("Month") != -1) {
        alert("month");
    } else {
        alert("year");
    }

});​
```

Of course, replace the `alerts` with your GA code.

http://jsfiddle.net/8EJMK/

And, since [`live` is deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/), you can use `on`.

> > As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

Depends on what version of jquery you are using:

```
$('div.subscribe a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).html().indexOf("Month") != -1) {
        alert("month");
    } else {
        alert("year");
    }

});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8EJMK/1/

You may also want to change this:

```
_gaq.push(["_trackEvent", "Subscriptions", "Clicked Month", This.attr( "title" )]);
```

To this:

```
_gaq.push(["_trackEvent", "Subscriptions", "Clicked Month", $(this).attr( "title" )]);
```

`This` isn't working. Should be `$(this)`.

Comment: Sorry, I do have a statement This = $(this) which I missed while writing the code on stackoverflow.. I have updated the above code. I dont have any javasript errors. Basically, all my events dont seem to be registered on GA. Some are.